# Moving users table (with encrypted passwords) to a different application

Tags: encryption, devise, passwords, bcrypt

I currently have a users table in a rails app, where the passwords are encrypted using devise/ bcrypt.

How can this table be migrated to be used with another application(react + non-rails backend)? I won't be able to use the existing db. Will need to replicate the data in a new table for the new app.

Is it possible/ right to use the same bcrypt encryption logic on the new system or would I have to get users to change password?

Comment: There is a good chance that you can further use the BCrypt hashes. Especially if both applications are based on PHP, you should be able to use the [password_verify()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) function to verify the login password.

Comment: Thanks Martin. The app is on rails as mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in luck; you're using a [well defined](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/usenix99/provos/provos_html/node5.html) password hash (good on you!). It has not been formally standardized, but as it is commonly used and implemented often, that should not pose significant problems. Of course there are better alternatives today such as scrypt and Argon2 but bcrypt may suffice - if correctly used, the work factor is set high and the passwords secure enough of course.

Because it is standardized and quite commonly used, it is very likely that you can find implementations in most programming languages. If you however run into problems it is more likely to be *because of encoding issues* than anything else. Most importantly, bcrypt acts on *bytes* rather than passwords. You should be using the same *character encoding* for your password (UTF-8 is recommended) to make sure that your implementations are compatible. Make sure you test with uncommon characters before you switch and leave a sizable part of your users in the dark.